# jQuery - slide repeat animation on click - loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-animate, infinite-loop

What i want to  achieve is when the users click **right** , the **green** layer slides left and a **red** box / **blue** box  will appear towards the end.

when we i reach the **blue** box i want the animation to continuing loops back to the **start** instead goin blank like here.

any help or advice appreciated, thanks

see this fiddle for better idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/TheDeveloper/5LF8d/8/    (click and hold right btn)

```
var main_box = $("div.main_box:first");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#left').mousedown(left_scrolling);
    $('#right').mousedown(right_scrolling);
    $('#right').mouseup(stopScrolling);
    $('#left').mouseup(stopScrolling);
});

function stopScrolling() {
    // stop increasing scroll position
    main_box.stop();

}

function left_scrolling() {
    main_box.animate({
        left: '+=50'
    }, 100, 'linear', left_scrolling);
}

function right_scrolling() {
    main_box.animate({
        left: '-=50'
    }, 100, 'linear', right_scrolling);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function right_scrolling() {
        if($('.last_box').offset().left < -$('.last_box').width())
            main_box.css('left','0px');
            ...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LF8d/12/)

For left Scrolling

```
function left_scrolling() {
        if($('.main_box').offset().left+50 >= 0)
            main_box.css('left',(-main_box.width()+window.innerWidth)+'px');
            ...
```

Comment: thanks this seem a lot simpler solution,  if i was to extend this and add left scrolling option how would i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the bounds of your main_box and check for those boundary conditions in your scrolling functions.

```
$(".main_box").position()
Object {top: 401, left: -3558.5}
```

If your left bounds are lower then say -3000 you could use offset to 'wrap' the object back to the other side:

Psuedocode

```
if(Object.left < -3000){
     $(".main_box").offset({top: 401, left: 3558});
}
```

A similar conditional check and statement would be needed to wrap the div if it's traveling the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/5LF8d/10/

```
var main_box = $("div.main_box:first");
window.leftVal=0;
window.limit=parseInt($('.last_box').css('left').replace(/\D/g,''));
window.limit+=$('.last_box').width();
window.limit+=100;
window.limit=window.limit*(-1);

function right_scrolling() {
    main_box.animate({
        left: '-=50'
    }, 100, 'linear', right_scrolling);
    window.leftVal-=50;
    if(window.leftVal<=window.limit){
        main_box.css('left','0px');
        window.leftVal=0;
    }
```

Comment: this solution seems more robust, again if i was to extend this and add left scrolling option how would i go about it?